# Iterate raster data error 00964

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, zonal-statistics, iteration

I'm building a model in arcmap 10.7 model builder to determine zonal statistics for multiple raster in a geodatabase. The model works, but only when i run it through model builder. When I try to run it as a tool I get error 000964 - specified extent is invalid. Also, when I add tools to the model, I will often get the error, breaking my model. I get this error whether or not I use a raster or shapefile as my feature zone. All data I'm using is in the same projection. Relevant pictures are below.

[image: Erro code on tool screen]

[image]

Comment: This has also occurred for me with Iterate Rasters when I ran the model within Model Builder.